# Versioning information in classpath

Tags: java, classloader

I am creating an API library that will be deployed to customer's on-premise applications.  This on-premise application contains independent plugin modules that contain the API library as a dependency.  Each application may have several of the plugins, therefore many copies of the API library.

I would like to have the flexibility to evolve the API library, while avoiding classloader conflicts.  An OSGI implementation is not an option at this time. I am wondering if anyone has  placing versioning information in the classpath, as to create different instantiations of the classes, as a way to avoid conflicts.

e.g.

User.java in package com.product.v2014_04 (1st version)

User.java in package com.product.v2014_05 (2nd version)

Does anyone have experience doing this, or know of any popular implementations that use this method to avoid classpath collisions?  Pros/cons?

Much appreciated

Comment: This is not a good approach for standard API versioning... every client using that API will need to be changed with every version. I suggest to have just the newest version on classpath and only make backwards compatible changes. If you need to break the backwards compatibility, then that might be the time to introduce new package name.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What if the API library was always packaged alongside of each plugin as a dependency (e.g. fat jar)?  I know this leads to code duplication, but is it valid in this case?

Comment: I think that code duplication is not that much of an issue if it is not SOURCE CODE duplication. If it just a packaging "thing", then its OK. Just make sure that you don't need to share instances between plugins... you know, `Foo.class != Foo.class` problems.

Comment: Also some major frameworks bundle their core dependencies inside their own packages to prevent conflicts with user libraries. For example Spring Framework repackages CGLIB inside its own packages. But that can be applied only for really internal non-shared dependencies (even not shared with other dependencies in your library). http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cglib/package-summary.html

Comment: I couldn't remember where I saw this before but then it came to me: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3. So putting the major version number at the end of the package name seems like a common approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache does this with some of their libraries.  If you look at an older version of commons-lang ([such as 2.6](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/)), the packages all live in `org.apache.commons.lang`.  Go grab a current version of it ([such as 3.3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/)) though, and you'll notice that all the packages have been renamed to `org.apache.commons.lang3`.

When I recently migrated an app from 2.6 to 3.3, it was a bit of a pain to go through and fix all my import statements, but it certainly got the point through that this was a major version change and I needed to pay attention to how I was using the code.